# OCR (optical character recognition) for Indian languages - segmentation

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation, octave, morphological-operations

Can any one help me in how to extract a table from the whole document image and segment it? I have done segmentation for the document image which has only text by using the projection profile. So please help me how to extract the table from the whole document image. I want only table to be extracted from the document. Please give me an idea how to do it. I want to continue my project using the projection profiles only.

---

i have done the segmentation manually for the document image which was consisting only text using projection profile manually i din't use the tables in it. now i want to extract the contents of the table in an image without using the formulas or any transforms can you help me.

Comment: Do you have sample images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the double difference method or you can also use the hough transform,Bounding Box method by which you can segment the document image by detecting the table in the given document image.

Answer (score 1):

Why do not use hough transform for finding lines and then finding table region?

you can use hough transform to find horizontal and vertical lines. and then extract region of lines.